# Prevent typing more than one space in VSCode with the exception of the start of a line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to restrict more than one space to be typed in VS Code unless it is before the first non-space in a line.

Additionally, if you open a file that was like that already I want those multi-spaces to be removed when saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [Trailing Spaces](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shardulm94.trailing-spaces) - it looks like a workaround for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are really looking for a formatter for these two functionalities: format on type and format on save.  However, you can get the first function - "restrict more than one space to be typed in Visual Studio Code unless it is before the first non-space in a line" with the help of an extension [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips).

For setting up that extension, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562886/836330

Then say in your `all.hsnips` file put this:

```
snippet `(\S)( ){2,}` "found 2 consecutive spaces with no non-whitespace characters preceding" A
``rv = m[1] + " "``
endsnippet
```

That will work in all language files, you can restrict it to certain languages as mentioned in that answer linked to.

Run the command `HyperSnips: Reload Snippets`.

Basically you are running a snippet that uses `(\S)( ){2,}` as the prefix.  It will be triggered whenever it detects two or more spaces in a row and will replace them with just one!

The snippet will only be triggered if those two spaces are preceded by a non-whitespace (so some character) and thus your second requirement that multiple spaces be allowed before the first character in a line.

It also works **between existing words** if you go there to edit - you will not be able to add a space to an existing space!!

Demo:

[image: space restrict demo]

The gif doesn't really capture it well but every time I am trying to write a second consecutive space it deletes it leaving only the one.

---

Your second question was "if you open a file that was like that already I want those multispaces to be removed when saved".

I suggest running a script on save.  Using, for example, [Trigger on Task Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.triggertaskonsave).  In your settings:

```
"triggerTaskOnSave.tasks": {

  "stripSpaces": [
    "**/*.txt"   // here restricting it to .txt files
  ],
},
```

This runs the `stripSpaces` task whener you save a `.txt` file.  That task (in tasks.json) could look like:

```
{
  "label": "stripSpaces",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "awk -f stripSpaces.awk ${relativeFile} > temp; mv temp ${relativeFile}"
}
```

which runs this `stripSpaces.awk` script:

```
# strip multiple consecutive spaces from a file
# unless they are the beginning of the line

BEGIN   {
    regex="\\S( ){2,}";
    }
{

if (match($0,regex))    {

    gsub(/( ){2,}/, " ")
    print
}
else print
}
```

Demo:

[image: awk strip spaces on save demo]